# Chrome extension, popup does not display correctly for dynamic popup DOM modification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension, a simple feature I want it to have is that when some clicks on the extension icon, it finds some info on the current page that my extension is visiting, and send the message from my content script to my popup, and my popup will add those info to it. now I pretty much finished all the work, there is only one problem left which is the layout of my popup does not display correctly. I have some thought about why it happens, I think it is because since the popup opens when you click on the icon, and then it finds the info on the page, and then it sends the message back to my popup, but the size of popup is already defined and displayed, so it does not rend it correctly, am I right? How should I fix it.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Please edit it to be readable and isolate your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your content script should retrieve the *info* from the current page immediately (on load) and send this information to the background script.

The background script can store this information either in a variable, or in localStorage/Chrome storage. When opening the popup you can retrieve this information and show it immediately. This way you would avoid the racing condition.